# how to click the button with beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

I want to click the button before scrape data

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; nl-nl; SAMSUNG GT-I9505 Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.5 Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://berdu.id/cek-resi?courier=sicepat&code=000361453759"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

how to do it right

Comment: What data are you actually after?

Comment: with BS4 you can't click the button, you will need to use Selenium for that. as @Qharr mentions, let know what you are trying to achieve.